# Ionic 3 error, exec proxy not found for :: PayPalMobile :: init

Tags: cordova, paypal, ionic3

I follow the steps to install and work with [PayPal-Cordova-Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/paypal/)

and everything goes ok!
But when I run the command:

```
ionic cordova run browser
```

I got this error :

```
Error: exec proxy not found for :: PayPalMobile :: init
( Missing Command Error cdv-plugin-paypal-mobile-sdk.js:41 )
```

and even when I try it on my android device I get the same problem.

can anyone help me to understand what happens and what wrong I have done !?

Answer (score -1):

**I solve it,**
all what i do is : run this command after plugged in my device

> ionic cordova run android --device

(ionic cordova run browser is not working with me)

and i add this lines to my main.ts

> import {enableProdMode} from '';
>   enableProdMode();